# Modificar los primeros dígitos de números de teléfonos inválidos en una nueva columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

```
    |Cod_Cliente|Tipo_Teléfono| Teléfono       |Longitud|Primeros_Dígitos|Invalido|

      |01         |Residencia   |809 000 0100  |10      |809             |0       |
      |02         |Residencia   |1829 003 0000 |11      |1829            |1       |
      |03         |Residencia   |8009 000 0100 |11      |800             |1       |
      |04         |Residencia   |8 29 050 0000 |10      |829             |1       |
      |05         |Residencia   |8049 000 0200 |11      |804             |1       |
```

Soy muy nuevo en python y
esta es mi tabla: Lo que he tratado de hacer y aun no consigo es de la columna **Teléfono** modificar los primeros dígitos inválidos. **Los números inválidos se representan por el numero 1.** [1829 debería ser 829] [ 8009:809] [8 29 :829][8049:849]. Las modificaciones con los nuevos números tenerlos en otra columna, solo los modificados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La lógica a utilizar está bastante clara, salvo un importante "detalle", que luego comentaré.

Supongamos que tienes ya escrita una función, llamada `arregla_numero()` a la que pasas como parámetro un número de teléfomo "malo" y te lo devuelve "bien". En ese caso, basta aplicar esa función a los elementos de la columna `"Teléfono"` cuyo campo `"Invalido"` sea 1, mediante una mezcla de un filtro Pandas y `DataFrame.apply()`, así:

```
df["Teléfono_bien"] = df[df["Invalido"] == 1]["Teléfono"].apply(arregla_numero)
```

Esto haría lo que buscas, siempre que la función `arregla_numero()` haga bien su trabajo.

## El problema

El problema es precisamente escribir esa función `arregla_numero()`, ya que **no está claro** el mecanismo que sigues para decidir cómo "arreglar" un número. Pones varios ejemplos, pero no es fácil sacar de ahí una regla general. Tus ejemplos son:

- 1829 -> 829. Vale, parece que el teléfono ha de comenzar por 8, por lo que podemos quitar los dígitos que sobren hasta el primer 8
- 8009 -> 809. Este es más difícil. Ya empezaba por 8, pero parece que debería tener tres dígitos en vez de cuatro. En todo caso ¿cuál sobra? ¿Por qué ha de ser convertido en 809 y no en 800 por ejemplo?
- 8 29 -> 829. Este parece fácil. Si hay espacios entre los tres primeros dígitos hay que eliminarlos
- 8049 -> 849. Este es parecido al segundo caso, y parece aplicar la misma regla: si tiene cuatro dígitos, eliminar el segundo ¿es esta una regla general?
- etc.? ¿No pueden aparecer muchas más casuísticas?

En cualquier caso, cuando la casuística esté clara, podríamos escribir la función `arreglar_numero()` que maneje los diferentes casos. Por ejemplo, una función que manejaría correctamente los tres ejemplos anteriores podría ser:

```
def arregla_numero(num):
  # Quitar todos los espacios que haya en el número
  num = "".join(num.split())

  # Si tras la compactación del número hay 11 dígitos, alguno sobra
  if len(num) == 11:
    # Si el primero no es un 8, ese sobraba
    if not num.startswith("8"):
      num = num[1:]
    # En otro caso, el que sobra es el segundo dígito
    else:
      num = num[0] + num[2:]

  # Aqui ya tenemos un número de 10 dígitos, y lo devolvemos
  # insertando espacios tras los 3 primeros y los 3 siguientes
  return " ".join([num[:3], num[3:6], num[6:]])
```

Como digo, esta función corrige adecuadamente los casos de tu ejemplo, pero no está para nada claro si es lo bastante general como para cubrir otros casos que se te presenten. Por ejemplo, si en algún caso hubiera 12 dígitos en el teléfono, no funcionará correctamente.

Debes "recopilar" los casos malos y las "recetas" necesarias para convertirlos en buenos, y programar una función `arregla_numero()` en base a esto. Una vez la tengas, puedes aplicarla "de golpe" a todos los números malos con la línea de código que mostré al principio de esta respuesta.

(y en las filas en las que la columna Invalido tenía ceros, la nueva columna "Teléfono_bien" tendrá un `NaN`)

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Los primeros dígitos que tengo que modificar son todos aquellos que formen el : 809 , 829  y 849. Tengo varios casos, ademas de los que puse como ejemplo. Tu código me ayudara mucho en lo que tengo que trabajar. Infinitas gracias!!!